# Unable to print entered values in console

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm trying to print the entered values after clicking save button in `console.log()` after clicking it's printing

> SecureElement: [object HTMLInputElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

in the both inputs

Below I'm pasting my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my HTML file

```
<lightning-layout-item>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="
            slds-input
            slds-text-align_center
            slds-var-m-bottom_large
        "
        value={firstName}
        placeholder="First Name">
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="
            slds-input
            slds-text-align_center
            slds-var-m-bottom_large
        "
        value={lastName}
        placeholder="Last Name">
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item size="3">
    <div class="slds-text-align_center">
        <lightning-button
            label="Save"
            slot="action"
            onclick={handleButton}
        ></lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

and here's my JS file

```
firstName;
lastName;
handleButton(event) {
    this.firstName = this.template.querySelector('input');
    this.lastName = this.template.querySelector('input');
    console.log('First Name is: '+this.firstName+ ' And Last Name is: ' +this.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These values:

```
this.firstName = this.template.querySelector('input');
this.lastName = this.template.querySelector('input');
```

are the elements themselves - the `<input>` elements in your component. You want the *values* of those elements, so you would do

```
this.firstName = this.template.querySelector('input').value;
this.lastName = this.template.querySelector('input').value;
```

Comment: Hi David, it solved some of my problem, when i'm clicking save button it doesn't prints entered values instead it is printing Account Name. Don't know why? Kindly help brother

Comment: Hello David, I happen to solve the problem, I just had to insert a class name in my HTML file and called it in querySelector. Thank you for taking your time from your busy schedule.